# Mutators (set-functions) with return value?

Tags: c++, c++11

Im studying programming and I just started learning about set and get functions.

My questions is if it is common practise to use set-functions with a return value?
Like when the set-function performs validation i would like it to return true if the incoming value passes the validation.

Googled it and looked throug my course material and found nothing, only void set-functions everywhere!! :)

Thx

Comment: Depends on your setter, but yes, it's possible to return a success/failure indication.

Comment: Matter of choice I suppose, but I prefer void-returning setters which throw exceptions.

Comment: "Getters and setters" are generally questionable in C++, since they indicate that you're using a class only as a collection of data. It's generally preferable to design classes that have concrete, specific responsibilities, and expose an interface suitable for that responsibility.

Comment: @KerrekSB How about e.g. [std::ios::rdbuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf)? Isn't it a getter/setter? Is it a matter of backwards-compatibility or is it really needed?

Comment: @iavr It’s hard to imagine just yanking out `rdbuf` from stream classes without crippling them. However, the *whole* design of C++ IO streams is often criticised, and it’s quite probable that a modern, non-backwards compatible redesign of the API would result in something quite different, and potentially without setters.

Comment: @iavr: It's occasionally useful to have (re)settable components as part of a class design. I was just saying that you shouldn't, as a matter of habit, stamp out getters and setters for all your private members.

Comment: @KonradRudolph/KerrekSB Thanks both. I've always seen a suspicion against getters/setters which I understand, but not a clear-cut discussion when they are needed and when not. Another good example is QT library where again I understand the need to refresh an element on screen when updated, yet definition of getters/setters is so much a "matter of habit" (e.g. with macros) that I often doubt whether they are all needed.

Comment: @iavr You might want to look up some of Stroustrup's interviews, people often ask him about this. In general, if you need to maintain class invariants, that's when you use getters/setters. The typical example he gives for no invariant is an hypothetical `AddresssBookEntry`, with many string fields, where each field (possibly excluding an `id` field) can accept any value. Also, a 2D vector class with no responsibility other than holding in a pair of scalars and a set of utility operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core motivation for getter/setter is value validation / sanity check values so returning a bool is a common way to make known if operation occurred successfully:

```
bool Class::setSomething(int a)
{
  if (is_ok(a))
  {
    // set...
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

This is

- quick/easy to implement
- has smaller footprint than exception handling (although this is negligible these days)

but

- it can't pass back any extra information to the caller (why did it break?)
- is easier to ignore compared to exceptions

Comment: Thanks! This was just the answer I was after, and thats exactly how my set-functions look like!

Answer (score 5):

In some cases you may want to return the reference to `*this` from setter methods to implement [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). A simple example:

```
class C {
  int x,y;
public:
  C& setX(int value) { x = value; return *this; }
  C& setY(int value) { y = value; return *this; }
};
```

such class may be then used in the following way:

```
C c;
c.setX(1).setY(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the setter is doing.

My set functions which only assign values to class members are void

```
void Class::setParameter(Parameter param)
{
    m_parameter = param;
}
```

if the setter is doing more than this, I can envisage returning a boolean.